# Uploading multiple files in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I have been trying to upload multiple files in Laravel using the code below but it only uploads a single image. Please help

$files = $request->file('file');

```
    foreach ($files as $file){

        $filename = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $location = public_path('uploads/'.$filename);

        $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $filename);

        $filename_arr = [];
        array_push($filename_arr, $filename);
        $filename = json_encode($filename_arr);
        $upload->filename = $filename;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blade: As you want to upload multiple file append [] to the input type name property with multiple as below :

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple>
```

Logic:

```
if($request->hasFile('file'))
{
    $files = $request->file('file');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path().'/uploads, $filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, your code work fine, it's uploading all files. Does this mean that one cannot rename multiple files and two how do create a json object in the loop to store the filenames for say one user.

Comment: create a empty collection before foreach loop $file_names = collect(); and under the loop after getting the filename use this code $file_names->push($filename); after the loop end just dd($file_names); this will store all the file you uploaded